# How to import ag-grid-enterprise in my Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I wanted to use server-side-row-model in my Angular 7 project where I use ag-grid.
In my package.json I found ag-grid-enterprise is already there as

```
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0"
```

But inside node-modules/ag-grid-enterprise I do not find server-side-row-model. In the documentation it is advised as:

```
@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "~22.0.0"
```

So I try that in package.json. But it cannot import, neither I do find @ag-grid-enterprise inside node-modules.Neither can it import:

```
import { ServerSideRowModelModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

You do not need `@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model` if you've already had `ag-grid-enterprise`. Besides, make sure you also have the following packages:

- `ag-grid-angular` to make `AgGrid` works with `angular`
- `ag-grid-community`: to include all community features. `ag-grid-enterprise` only includes additional feature for enterprise users

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^20.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^20.0.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0",
```

Don't forget to register your module in your `app.module.ts`

```js
import { AgGridModule } from "ag-grid-angular";
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AgGridModule.withComponents([])],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

### Longer answer

There are 2 ways of importing AgGrid. Using `package` or `module`.

```
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0"
```

This one is a `package` which contains all of the feature. this is the easiest way to import

```
@ag-grid-enterprise/server-side-row-model": "~22.0.0"
@ag-grid-enterprise/xxxxx
```

This one is a separate `module`. It allows you to cherry-pick only the features you need. It helps reduce the bundle size but needs more time to setup correctly

**You cannot mix 2 of them together**. Either use `package` or `module`.

Comment: I will try this on Monday. This clarified many of my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happen with me.

"ag-grid-enterprise": "^20.0.0" Having one module others are missing,

Now I wondered how to add other modules